# Is it possible to access all resources in a terraform remote state that aren't declared as outputs

Tags: terraform, terraform-state

I am trying to get some references from terraform remote state, and have noticed some differences between `terraform state` resources / data, and using a `terraform_remote_state` data object.

For example, I have a terraform module that created an AWS managed directory, with no outputs. Within that module, I can see all resources in the state - e.g. `terraform state show aws_directory_service_directory.ad` gives me details on the directory - the directory ID, DNS server addresses, etc.

```
$ terraform state list
aws_directory_service_directory.ad
$ terraform state show aws_directory_service_directory.ad
# aws_directory_service_directory.ad:
resource "aws_directory_service_directory" "ad" {
    access_url        = "REDACTED"
    alias             = "REDACTED"
    dns_ip_addresses  = []
    .... etc ....
}
```

If I then create a new module and add a `terraform_remote_state` data object, i cannot access any properties of the directory - `data.terraform_remote_state.ad.outputs` is empty. From within this new module, if I only have the remote state data object, and apply (with no resources), and then use `terraform console` and show `data.terraform_remote_state.ad`, it looks like:

```
$ terraform console
> data.terraform_remote_state.ad
{
  "backend" = ".."
  "config" = { remote_state config shown here }
  "outputs" = {}
}
```

So the resources are in the state, but not accessible directly. Is this expected behaviour? Is there any way to access the resources in the remote state, or would I need to add attributes into outputs and use `data.terraform_remote_state.ad.outputs.whatever_attributes`?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why you can't do that?

Comment: Thanks Marcin - was helpful / correct answer - i have just marked it. will refactor the upstream module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only access `outputs`. From [docs](https://www.terraform.io/language/state/remote-state-data#alternative-ways-to-share-data-between-configurations):

> terraform_remote_state only **exposes output values**

You have to modify the parent module of the other setup and add required outputs.

The other way would be to develop your own, fully [custom data source](https://www.cloudwalker.io/2021/10/09/terraform-external-data-source/) to provide info that you need.